# PowerShell - Username existence check

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue with getting a value from Active Directory using PowerShell and comparing it against a string.

$username_AD = Get-AdUser "JSmith" -Properties SamAccountName | FT SamAccountName

The above value is stored in a variable as:

```
  echo $username_AD
  SamAccountName
  --------------
  JSmith
```

So when I run the below the condition is never true. The username JSmith does exist in AD.

```
  $username_AD = Get-AdUser "JSmith" -Properties SamAccountName | FT SamAccountName
  $username_value = "JSmith"
  IF ($username_value -eq $username_AD)
  {
      echo "Yes the username exists in Active Directory!"
  }
  else
  {
      echo "No the username does not exist in Active Directory"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare different object types.

The first thing to be aware of is `FT` or `Format-Table` is not producing a bunch of text, it's creating a `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData]` object.  try this:

```
$username_AD = (Get-AdUser "JSmith" -Properties SamAccountName).SAMAccountName
$username_value = "JSmith"
 IF ($username_value -like $username_AD)
   {
    Write-Output "Yes the username exists in Active Directory!"
   }
else
   {
    Write-Output "No the username does not exist in Active Directory"
   }
```

There are a couple things to remember, you want to compare strings so use `-like` not `-eq`, `Format-Table` is not creating a `[System.String]` object, which is what you are looking for, and you're using powershell so don't mix in commands like echo.  The Cmldet `Write-Output` is a lot more appropriate in this scenario.

Comment: Regardless, your problem stems from some misinterpretations of how PowerShell works.  You might find you save time and money by picking up an introductory PowerShell book.  I liked Learn PowerShell in a month of lunches.  You can finish it in a week or two and it really goes over a lot of the quirks of the shell.  The big lesson you learn is not to trust what you see in the shell.  When in doubt, examine the object type.